# Don't count your eggs before they hatch

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

Don't count your eggs before they hatch...

[image: egg1]
[image: egg2]
[image: egg3]
[image: egg4]
[image: egg5]
[image: egg6]
[image: egg7]
[image: egg8]
[image: egg9]

Comment: Where did you get the puzzle or did you make it yourself? You have to state this in your puzzle, or this question might be closed.

Comment: Nice puzzle! Free photos? Or giving attributions?

Comment: "And we won't count 10 Downing Street until it's Thatched." Sorry, I couldn't find a better joke.

Comment: Nice choice of pictures

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Each of these images besides the first

> has a letter that can fit in place of all of the eggs. Many different letters will fit in a single egg, but together they narrow it down to a single one.
>  (This is hinted by the first image, which tells you that all eggs are equal.)

These are:

> 2: j (junk, projection)
>  3: a (babble, pant, chap)
>  4: n (nice, swan, skin, spine)
>  5: b (bill, bed, batch, curb)
>  6: r (rod, ray, rang, care, root, tar)
>  7: a (ban, pat, last, pan, male, bay, wave)
>  8: d (dipper, done, side, deal, dent, code, wade, dice)
>  9: y (say, may, yam, lay, flay, pay, year, yet, spay)

So the answer is

> **JAN BRADY**, one of the characters on The Brady Bunch.

Comment: Is there any link between the final answer and the puzzle itself other than the obvious). ie does the answer have something to do with eggs in some way? just seems like a really random final answer...

Comment: Perhaps a permutation?

Comment: @Chris Honestly, not one that I know of. I tried to find one but had no luck.

Comment: Hopefully the OP will clarify!